# Debugging an automotive FM transmitter

Tags: radio, repair, transmitter

Transmitter is a 12V automotive audio-to-FM transmitter unit. Belkin Tunecast F8M066.

Receives both power and audio fine over the cables into the unit as measured on the board. 7.6 MHz crystal is running seemingly correctly. Frequency adjustment display and buttons all work great. No FM output detectable by an external receiver. I measured a 12V and 5V rail on the board.

One chip is marked L02 9V66W (an SO8). The main MCU's part number is scrubbed and is an SO22.

On antenna I don't seem to measure anything like a carrier at the current frequency (105 MHz) ; I only see a 2.2 MHz signal.

[image: underside]

Shown is underside (opposite display), with audio in at the top left, 12V in at the bottom left, and antenna the red wire at the bottom.

No obvious corrosion or blown caps. Hints on next steps for debugging? I can offer close-ups of different sections of the board on demand. Whole board is only about 1" by 2".

Comment: you can verify all the basic components in-situ as best as possible, but if that doesn't flush anything out and all you have is mystery ICs, it's pragmatic to replace.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a copy of Silicon Chip magazine's "Micromitter" that uses a now-obsolete Rohm 22 pins IC and a 7.6MHz crystal:

[image: Micromitter]

Comment: Interesting! That's a quite low-res image; could you share a link to the original?

Comment: https://www.siliconchip.com.au/Issue/2002/December/The+Micromitter+Stereo+FM+Transmitter ?

Comment: (I also found [this source](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-fYsYTJ1RhOs/VH2V6GOOXUI/AAAAAAAAJ7w/T8CdAtXePgw/s1600/DIY%2BMicromitter%2BStereo%2BFM%2BTransmitter.jpg))